# Can I set up a different password to login with?

Tags: login, password

I just switched from windows, and there I had the ability to set up multiple login options- you can enter your account password, or login with a PIN number/ other password, which I liked because I can let my friends use my computer without having to set up multiple accounts, or give away my administrating password I use for everything. Is there a way to do the same thing on ubuntu- create different ways to login?

Comment: Hey! Althought I didn't read the how-to, this seems to be what you are looking for: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90684/can-you-give-a-user-account-multiple-passwords

Answer (score 1):

You can create as many accounts as you wish. Log in as a non-admin user if you wish. For the most part this is not necessary as, unlike other OS, the admin account does NOT run with elevated privileges, it just has the ability to escalate privileges (using sudo).

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

You can not easily do what you envision in Debian/Ubuntu, but you can with RHEL/Fedora using selinux. Selinux allows you to sign in a single account with privileges defined at login .

Be warned, although opinions may vary, selinux is not generally considered "easy" or user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to create multiple users in Linux! It's as simple as

```
useradd Tim
useradd Paul
useradd Steve
```

You are also able to setup passwords for them to login as

```
passwd Tim
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
```

If you prefer not to use command line open up the system settings which can be found on the left side or top right of tool bar under the power symbol and locate User Accounts.

You will need to hit Unlock at the very top right corner, and type in your admin password. After that there should be a + sign at the very bottom left and you can fill in the fields with the desired values.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you let them use the guest login?  There is by default a guest user, who can browse the internet and do minor things.